# Class strange error

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Spring edition (STS) and I am getting a strange error in one of the classes in my project:

```
can not implement the missing methods, either due to compile errors can not implement the missing methods, either due to compile errors
```

The class causing this error name is `ItemDAO`, and it implements interface `IItemDAO`, and I am 100% sure that there are no un-implemented methods, but Eclipse insists that there are some un-implemented methods, and when I click on the class name and select implement un-implemented methods I get the above error.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here and how to fix this problem?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact error message? Something about its wording seems off.

Comment: Try to clean your project.

Comment: And/or restarting Eclipse.

Comment: try to put @Override at top of all(I mean methods from interface) methods in extending class, and see is there any function you are getting an issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Just had the issue and fixed it by cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

What the messages says is that since you have compile errors, Eclipse cannot perform the auto-implement action.

The compilation errors are most probably, either in `ItemDAO` class or `IItemDAO` interface. Fix them first and then retry the auto-implement action.

Answer (score 0):

- The error message states that you have not implemented all the
  methods in `IItemDAO`.
- While you try to order eclipse to implement it automatically, it can't be done, because there are compilation errors in the methods (which are still to be implemented or unimplemented) in `IItemDAO`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the jre, use jdk. It will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Here is the error message :

> cannot implement the missing methods, either due to compile errors or the project build path does not resolve all dependency

The issue was resolved after cleaning the project as suggested

Answer (score 0):

Go to Source -> cleanup -> besides there is a button configure click on it -> check Enable project specific settings -> apply and close

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the problem, at my situation (I use Maven). I want use struts `ServletRequestAware`, and it need the `servlet-api.jar`. So you need to add Tomcat runtimes.

Go to your project, right click->Properties->Project Facets->Runtimes-> add Tomcat.

That`s all.

Comment: It must be your implements method have the error as other people say.